# Triggering a VBScript from a C# dotnet core API

Tags: c#, vbscript, permissions, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API running in IIS on an app server, which needs to be able to trigger a series of VBScripts which open, populate and print a number of documents. The Application Pool being used by the API has its identity set to a domain user with the permissions required to successfully run the scripts, `Fooser`. If I log on as that user and run the script `Bar.vbs` it executes successfully.

When I try to run `Bar.vbs` from the API using a `Process`, though, it fails on trying to open the template document. I added some logging in `Bar.vbs` of the `WScript.Network` `Username` property and, sure enough, it is `Fooser` (or whatever user I set it to be).

`C:\Company\CompanyDocuments\Scripts\Bar.vbs` looks like this:

```
' -- Script Start

Set logShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWord = OpenWord("C:\Company\CompanyDocuments\test.doc")
Set EVENT_INFORMATION = 4

' -- Script End

Function OpenWord(wrdDoc2Open)
Dim Word
Const wdDialogFilePrintSetup = 97
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
logShell.LogEvent EVENT_INFORMATION, "Test 1: opened word"
Word.Visible= True
' Set Options in Word to try to speed up document processing.
With Word.Options
        .CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
        .CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
        .SuggestSpellingCorrections = False
        .SuggestFromMainDictionaryOnly = False
        .CheckGrammarWithSpelling = False
        .ShowReadabilityStatistics = False
End With
logShell.LogEvent EVENT_INFORMATION, "Test 2: opening document " & wrdDoc2Open
logShell.LogEvent EVENT_INFORMATION, "Test 2.1: User" & CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

Set g_objDoc = Word.documents.Open(wrdDoc2Open,,True)

If Err Then 
    logShell.LogEvent EVENT_INFORMATION, "Test Error."
End If

logShell.LogEvent EVENT_INFORMATION, "Test 3: opened document"
Set OpenWord = Word
End Function
```

And the process in being run by the API is:

```
var scriptProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = @"cscript",
        WorkingDirectory = scriptsPath.ToString(),
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        Arguments = $"//B //Nologo {fileName} {(arguments.Count != 0 ? string.Join(' ', arguments) : string.Empty)}"
    }
};
scriptProcess.Start();
scriptProcess.WaitForExit();
scriptProcess.Close();
```

The process is successfully starting the script, but the script is failing without reaching either the `"Test Error."` or the `"Test 3: opened document"` statements.

This is integrating with a legacy system so it's simply too much work to replace the vbs.